# Upgraded Lubuntu 14.10 to 15.04, now get "Kernel Panic: not syncing VFS: Unable to mount root fs."

Tags: boot, grub2, lubuntu

I have a home server with Lubuntu installed. A few days ago, a Ubuntu update dialog box appeared, and I seemed to update to the latest version with no trouble (at least, no apparent errors).

However, now when I reboot the server, Lubuntu does autoboot to the desktop as it always has before. It now brings up the GNU Grub interface for loading Ubuntu (with options for memtest etc.). The first, autoloading option, entitled 'Ubuntu' tries to load Ubuntu but hangs on the following error:

```
Kernel Panic: not syncing VFS: Unable to mount root fs.
```

However, I CAN load my usual Lubuntu desktop if I go down to the second option on the Grub interface:

```
Advanced options for Ubuntu
```

And then selecting:

```
Ubuntu, with Linux 3.16.0-36-generic
```

It loads Lubuntu 15.04, and all my settings, installs and all SEEM to be intact.
I would, however, like to just go back to Lubuntu loading as usual on boot!

Thank you for your help.

Answer (score 0):

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:danielrichter2007/grub-customizer
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install grub-customizer
```

Then pick `Ubuntu, with Linux 3.16.0-36-generic` to be the default boot (since it works for you). After this go to the following file:

```
sudo gedit /etc/default/grub
```

Then change the grub timeout

```
GRUB_TIMEOUT=0
```

Save and reboot.

Comment: Hmm weird... I have a wired connection to my server, as usual, which shows in the network options, but I'm not connected to the web. Therefore cannot add the repository... Any idea why this might have happened?

Comment: What is the output when you try add the repository? also can you wget the following: https://launchpad.net/~danielrichter2007/+archive/ubuntu/grub-customizer/+files/grub-customizer_4.0.6-0ubuntu1~ppa1v_amd64.deb

Comment: It's very long, and cannot paste, but it ends PPAException: 'Error reading https://launchpad.net/apo/1.0/~danielrichter2007: [Errno -3] temporary failure in name resolution

Comment: I just read you're on a server as well. grub-costumizer is using a GUI interface. You can manually go into the grub files and change the default boot entry. So head into the grub.cfg (I believe it is there)